# PHP & ZF2 / Comparison: expected == actual

Tags: php, coding-style, zend-framework2, comparison

does anyone know why some developers (especially seen in the sources of Zend Framework 2) write the expected value before the actual value in comparisons?

Example:

```
if (true === $actualValue) { ... }
```

instead of

```
if ($actualValue === true) { ... }
```

This case is not defined in the PSR coding standard.

**Note:** There is a similar topic for c++ but without *really* helpful answers.

Comment: I thought it was as a way of eliminating the possibility of assignment within a condition accidentally (i.e. if you forget one of the equals signs). Not sure if that's the main reason, but I've seen that before. `true = $actualValue` throws a parse error, while `$actualValue = true` doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are seeing is [Yoda conditions](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions/). There is no standard defining these (at least not to my knowledge). They are merely a way to protect yourself against a common coding error (assignment in your conditions).

Example:

```
if( number = 4 ) // Works perfectly

if( 4 = number ) // Throws an exception
```

Comment: +1 for reading the question correctly (unlike I did) and knowing the reference :)

Comment: I had to look it up, but I did know the name, Jeff recently blogged about it: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Comment: Good god, I wish I could Give you another +1 for the laughs I just got from the link. I normally just read [Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. May the force be with you.